# Is this something like a lens? (proof search transformers/combinators)

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In automated theorem proving (proof search), I compose transformers of type

```
t :: Claim -> IO (Maybe (Claim, Proof -> Proof))
```

such that: when `t c` returns `Just (c', f)`, then `c'` implies `c` and a proof for `c` is obtained from a proof `p'` for `c'` by computing `f p'`.

Is this a lens, somehow? (If yes, what would it help?)

There's also a more general case (for several, or zero, subgoals)

```
ts :: Claim -> IO (Maybe ([Claim], [Proof] -> Proof))
```

The `IO` part is important because these transformers do substantial work (calling external processes), and I might want to impose timeouts.

Answer (score 3):

I can't readily see how lenses could help with that. However, reordering your monadic stack and using monad transformers should make composition much easier, and also open up the possibility of abstracting from `IO` in the cases you don't need impurity:

```
t' :: Claim -> MaybeT IO (Claim, Proof -> Proof)
```

If you want or need to keep using an existing implementation of `t` in spite of the more cumbersome type, you can lift its result to `MaybeT` with:

```
(MaybeT . return =<<) . lift :: m (Maybe b) -> MaybeT m b
```

It is worth noting that `Claim -> (Claim, Proof -> Proof)` is equivalent to `State Claim (Proof -> Proof)`, so it *might* be possible to go even further:

```
t'' :: StateT Claim (MaybeT IO) (Proof -> Proof)
```